# Getting database values via foreign key in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a list of items that are tagged and I would like to list the tag name next to each item.  For example:

*My cool list item - "Awesome Tag"*

Each list item has one, and only one, tag; `tag_id` is a foreign key in my list table and it is a required field in my model.

I have been thinking about the ways I could try and do this but am not quite sure on best practices...

1. Create a `@tags` class variable with an array of all tags and, for each list item, loop through it to see if the ids match.  If they do, display the tag name.
2. Have a custom method in my `list_item` model where I loop through the list items and append the tag name to the list object so that I could access it in my view via `@list_item.tag_name` (I'm not sure if this can even be done this way).
3. Write a custom SQL query to get the tag name into the active record results.  For instance:

   ```
   SELECT list.descriptions, tag.name 
   FROM list_items AS list 
   INNER JOIN tags AS tag 
   ON(list.tag_id = tag.id)
   ```

While it appears to be the most resource friendly, the third option seems like a lot of work for something so basic.

Holler if you'd like any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use:

```
@list_item.tag.name
```

It doesn't need any extra code, so it's understandable to those who aren't familiar with `delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate

Add this line in list_item model

```
delegate :name, :to => :tag, :prefix => true
```

Now you can access tag name by using

> @list_item.tag_name

This is more like to your second option.

See more details about delegate here:
http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/

Comment: I'm going to check out delegation and do a little bit more research into this.  Thank you for the lead.